# Initializing matcher with initialized string, getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to initialize Matcher in Java but continue to get a NPE regardless if the string is initialized and not null.

Here is the code:

```
pattern.compile("\\s");
System.out.println("In = " + in);
matcher = pattern.matcher(in);
```

And the output of the print statement:

> In = 2 2 + //this is a comment

So clearly in is initialized, what could be throwing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign return value of static method `Pattern.compile` to an object of type `Pattern`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
```

then use it as:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(in);
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't realize my silly mistake. I had declared "Pattern pattern" earlier and assumed compile was all I need to call afterwards.

Comment: Yes `Pattern.compile` is a static method that returns an object of type `Pattern`.